# Correlation matrix with significance testing in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, correlation, p-value

I am wondering if there is already a package in R that can spit out a correlation matrix with significance testing such as with SPSS or Statistica? At the moment I am having to produce a correlation matrix (using **ggplot2 geom_tile**) and separate significance testing using **cor.test**. It would be great to combine the two into a single graphic.

Here is a subset of the real data that I am using.

```
           X         Var2   CorrValue        pValue
1         AAAA       V1   0.96240707       1.802995e-07
2         BBBB       V1  0.85385864       1.336821e-03
3         CCCC       V1  0.65835637       1.166884e-01
4         DDDD       V1 -0.54059196       3.673812e-01
5         EEEE       V1  0.29001017       1.000000e+00
6         FFFF       V1 -0.92886462       1.329147e-05
7         GGGG       V1  0.44273554       7.732118e-01
8         HHHH       V1 -0.80137821       7.597324e-03
9         IIII       V1  0.93013470       1.193781e-05
10        JJJJ       V1 -0.80781321       6.605418e-03
11        KKKK       V1 -0.42663765       7.948182e-01
12        LLLL       V1  0.80636700       6.771520e-03
13        MMMM       V1  0.85018600       1.543993e-03
14        NNNN       V1  0.90895906       6.210643e-05
15        OOOO       V1  0.88107227       3.669339e-04
16       PPPPP       V1  0.87853038       4.149637e-04
17       QQQQQ       V1  0.80868505       6.563540e-03
18       RRRRR       V1  0.79054501       1.014822e-02
19        AAAA       V2 -0.69444018       7.088595e-02
20        BBBB       V2 -0.75584928       2.402074e-02
21        CCCC       V2 -0.82625132       3.674920e-03
22        DDDD       V2  0.76938820       1.724964e-02
23        EEEE       V2 -0.07953878       1.000000e+00
24        FFFF       V2  0.64012814       1.335781e-01
25        GGGG       V2 -0.13886613       1.000000e+00
26        HHHH       V2  0.67113002       9.731157e-02
27        IIII       V2 -0.71736303       4.923524e-02
28        JJJJ       V2  0.79422494       9.297322e-03
29        KKKK       V2  0.65673252       1.166884e-01
30        LLLL       V2 -0.83719167       2.506800e-03
```

The code that I am using to produce only the **heat-map or correlation matrix** is as follows:

```
    ggplot(longData, aes(X, Var2))+
  geom_tile(data=longData, aes(fill=CorrValue), color="white")+
  geom_text(aes(fill = longData$CorrValue, label = round(longData$CorrValue, 2)))+
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours=cm.colors(4),
                       limit=c(-1,1),name="Correlation\n(Pearson)")+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size=12,  colour='black'),
        axis.text.y=element_text(colour='black'),
        panel.background=element_rect(colour="black", fill=NA))+
  coord_equal()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT: I now have managed to create a data frame with both the correlation coefficient and p-values, thanks to Tim. However I am now wanting to plot the significance values on the heatmap and indicate it as stars or whatever is the easiest to do. At the moment I am only after two levels i.e. <.01 and >.01.**

Comment: The plot you provide as an example has nothing to do with significance testing - how does it relate to your question?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear in my question. The code is to produce the correlation matrix or the heat-map. I have edited the question to make this clear. I want to be able to show significance testing in it using starts (***) or bold/italics text. I don't know how to get to that. At the moment I am having to use cor.test for each pair of variables to test significance which is not helping. Also using cor.test I am unable to show in the heat map where significant correlations occur.

Comment: Function `corrplot` in `corrplot` package might be of some help.

Comment: @VGu how does heatmap of correlation values relate to significance testing in your question? Those are two different things..

Comment: I am trying to plot the significance values on top of the correlation heatmap. For example there could be a correlation value of 0.96 but p value >0.01. So I would like to indicate this on the heatmap either by bolding the correlation value or using a series of stars (*, **, ***) in the box with the associated correlation value. Hope it makes sense now. Sorry once again for the confusion.

Comment: @Tim- I have after a bit of a struggle managed to get the correlation coefficient and significant values in a single long form table. How do I go about implementing the ability to in some way show significant values in my heatmap? I'm only after two values of significance at this stage i.e. p<0.01 and p>0.01.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would like to think I have managed to find the solution. Please feel free to check out the code and correct me if I'm wrong.

```
#Create a column with the stars

    longformData$stars <- cut(longformData$pValue, breaks=c(-Inf, 0.001, 0.01, 0.05, Inf), 
                           label=c("***", "**", "*", ""))  # Create column of significance labels
```

Final Plot code

```
    ggplot(longformData, aes(X, Var2))+
  geom_tile(data=longformData, aes(fill=CorrValue), color="white")+
  geom_text(aes(label=stars), color="black", size=5,vjust=-1.5)+
  geom_text(aes(fill = longformData$value, label = round(longformData$CorrValue, 2)))+
  scale_fill_gradient(low='red', high='green',
                      limit=c(-1,1),name="Correlation\n(Pearson)")+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size=12,  colour='black'),
        axis.text.y=element_text(colour='black'),
        panel.background=element_rect(colour="black", fill=NA))+
  coord_equal()
```

The output image is attached. If there is an easier way to approach this I would be happy to know.

[image: Correlation heatmap with significance values]

Thank you all for all your help.

Answer (score 3):

Package [psych](http://personality-project.org/r/psych/) outputs correlation with corresponding p-values

```
> psych::corr.test(mtcars)
Call:psych::corr.test(x = mtcars)
Correlation matrix 
       mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
mpg   1.00 -0.85 -0.85 -0.78  0.68 -0.87  0.42  0.66  0.60  0.48 -0.55
cyl  -0.85  1.00  0.90  0.83 -0.70  0.78 -0.59 -0.81 -0.52 -0.49  0.53
disp -0.85  0.90  1.00  0.79 -0.71  0.89 -0.43 -0.71 -0.59 -0.56  0.39
hp   -0.78  0.83  0.79  1.00 -0.45  0.66 -0.71 -0.72 -0.24 -0.13  0.75
drat  0.68 -0.70 -0.71 -0.45  1.00 -0.71  0.09  0.44  0.71  0.70 -0.09
wt   -0.87  0.78  0.89  0.66 -0.71  1.00 -0.17 -0.55 -0.69 -0.58  0.43
qsec  0.42 -0.59 -0.43 -0.71  0.09 -0.17  1.00  0.74 -0.23 -0.21 -0.66
vs    0.66 -0.81 -0.71 -0.72  0.44 -0.55  0.74  1.00  0.17  0.21 -0.57
am    0.60 -0.52 -0.59 -0.24  0.71 -0.69 -0.23  0.17  1.00  0.79  0.06
gear  0.48 -0.49 -0.56 -0.13  0.70 -0.58 -0.21  0.21  0.79  1.00  0.27
carb -0.55  0.53  0.39  0.75 -0.09  0.43 -0.66 -0.57  0.06  0.27  1.00
Sample Size 
[1] 32
Probability values (Entries above the diagonal are adjusted for multiple tests.) 
      mpg cyl disp   hp drat   wt qsec   vs   am gear carb
mpg  0.00   0 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.22 0.00 0.01 0.10 0.02
cyl  0.00   0 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.01 0.00 0.04 0.08 0.04
disp 0.00   0 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.20 0.00 0.01 0.02 0.30
hp   0.00   0 0.00 0.00 0.17 0.00 0.00 0.00 1.00 1.00 0.00
drat 0.00   0 0.00 0.01 0.00 0.00 1.00 0.19 0.00 0.00 1.00
wt   0.00   0 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 1.00 0.02 0.00 0.01 0.20
qsec 0.02   0 0.01 0.00 0.62 0.34 0.00 0.00 1.00 1.00 0.00
vs   0.00   0 0.00 0.00 0.01 0.00 0.00 0.00 1.00 1.00 0.02
am   0.00   0 0.00 0.18 0.00 0.00 0.21 0.36 0.00 0.00 1.00
gear 0.01   0 0.00 0.49 0.00 0.00 0.24 0.26 0.00 0.00 1.00
carb 0.00   0 0.03 0.00 0.62 0.01 0.00 0.00 0.75 0.13 0.00

 To see confidence intervals of the correlations, print with the short=FALSE option
```

You can use [tidyr](http://blog.rstudio.org/2014/07/22/introducing-tidyr/) to transform the output to [long format](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf) to plot it as you wish:

```
X <- psych::corr.test(mtcars)
tidyr::gather(as.data.frame(cbind(V1=rownames(X$p), X$p)), key, value, -V1)
```